# Match characters class after the pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

With a text:

```
//asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/... //test/asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/...
//asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/... //test/asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/...
//asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/... //test/asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/...
//asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/... //test/asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/...
```

I would like to match all the `[` and `]` after first `...` . (To remove them. Replace them with non/empty char in `Notepad++`)

I know that:

- `[\[\]]` - matches ALL square brackets
- `(?<=\.\.\.).*` - matches only second part of the string (after `...`)

I cannot join this two operation together.

`((?<=\.\.\.).*)[\[\]]+` will create following group:
 `//test/asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq`

When I would rather have groups only with square brackets inside.

Is it even possible to run regex query on matched group?

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2kHQWd/2)

**Goal:**
Remove all square brackets from all right hand side paths only.

To be:

```
//asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/... //test/asdj/asdmaopifndqpw/asdkjlha/safd/waoqjerpq/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/...
//asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/... //test/asdj/asdmaopifndqpw/asdkjlha/safd/waoqjerpq/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/...
//asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/... //test/asdj/asdmaopifndqpw/asdkjlha/safd/waoqjerpq/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/...
//asdj/[asdmaopifndqpw]/[asdkjlha]/[safd]/[waoqjerpq]/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/... //test/asdj/asdmaopifndqpw/asdkjlha/safd/waoqjerpq/124152/124152-app/1jr-2rj1/...
```

Comment: What is your regex flavor/tool?

Comment: You can match using `(\.{3}.*?)(?:\/\[[^\]]*])+` and replace with `$1`

Comment: I've edited question with more details. I'm using Notepad++ regex system, but for nor I was testing it with regex101.

Comment: To remove all the pieces between square brackets, use `\[[^]]*\]` [regexp](https://regex101.com/r/Zk8jQJ/1)   BTW: what is the difference between "With a text:", and the text show after "To be:" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for matching:

```bash
(?:\.{3}|(?!^)\G)[^][]*\K[][]
```

Replace it with empty string.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2kHQWd/6)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\.{3}.*?`: Match 3 dots followed by 0 or more of any character
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. `(?!^)` makes sure we start matching from end of the previous match
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `[^][]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that are not `[` and `]`
- `\K`: Reset matched info
- `[][]`: Match a `[` or `]`

Comment: Unfortunately this solution captures " ... //test/asdj" as group and this is not what I'm looking for. I want to have groups containing only `[` amd `]` to be able to replace them. Thank you for your quick reply though.

Comment: Hi, I do not want to sound any rude or ungrateful but did you check your solution? Your regex does not capture any group thus it cannot be swapped with $1. As I replied to you I've also updated the question to reflect the result I would like to achieve. Please check it out.

Comment: @jarzyn: Comments and critiques are always welcome. `$1` was left over from previous solution that I have fixed. However if you look at the demo I had posted and explanation I have provided you will see highlighted text as your desired match. NP++ supports PCRE so it will work well in NP++

Comment: But again, your solution removes all the content related to brackets. I just want to remove brackets. Check my answer it's not perfect but it's what I'm counting on. Please check 'Goal' in the question.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion. I was under assumption that you want to remove all of `[...]` not just `[` and `]`.  I have rewritten my solution with a new demo. It should all work fine now.

Comment: That's simply amazing. Thank you!